# Retrieving the text of the selected <option> in <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the following:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">Test One</option>
    <option value="2">Test Two</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the text of the selected option (i.e. "Test One" or "Test Two") using JavaScript

`document.getElementsById('test').selectedValue` returns 1 or 2, what property returns the text of the selected option?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

```
function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}

var text = getSelectedText('test');
```

Comment: This answer is outdated, see @davidjb's answer below for a nice HTML5 one-liner.

Comment: @Christallkeks - the one-liner [throws an exception if nothing is selected](https://jsfiddle.net/mcu4ke23/). fewer lines isn't always better.

Answer (score 90):

If you use jQuery then you can write the following code:

```
$("#selectId option:selected").html();
```

Comment: since he wants the text, probably better to use `.text()`

Comment: Not to be confused with `$("#selectId option[selected]")`, which will select the option which has the "selected" attribute but might not be currently selected.

Comment: seems more complicated.!

Answer (score 56):

```
document.getElementById('test').options[document.getElementById('test').selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: It worked for me also, after trying all other options.

Comment: this wordk perfect!

Answer (score 36):

Under HTML5 you are be able to do this:

```
document.getElementById('test').selectedOptions[0].text
```

MDN's documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions indicates full cross-browser support (as of at least December 2017), including Chrome, Firefox, Edge and mobile browsers, but excluding Internet Explorer.

Comment: +1, meanwhile this is the way to go. The Firefox ticket is fixed and I even bothered opening MS Edge to verify that they support it, too.

Answer (score 29):

```
selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;
```

References:

- options collection, selectedIndex property: [HTML DOM Select Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp)
- text property: [HTML DOM Option Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp)
- exactly the answer of this question: [Option text Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_text.asp)

Comment: Easy to understand than the answer @wormhit gave. +1 for simplifying

Answer (score 7):

The `options` property contains all the `<options>` - from there you can look at `.text`

```
document.getElementById('test').options[0].text == 'Text One'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `selectedIndex` to retrieve the current selected `option`:

```
el = document.getElementById('elemId')
selectedText = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text
```

Answer (score 4):

this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText

Answer (score 2):

If you found this thread and wanted to know how to get the selected option text via event here is sample code:

```
alert(event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the select list object, to identify its own selected options index.
From there - grab the inner HTML of that index.
And now you have the text string of that option.

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML);">
       <option value="">Select Actions</option>
       <option value="1">Print PDF</option>
       <option value="2">Send Message</option>
       <option value="3">Request Review</option>
       <option value="4">Other Possible Actions</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: `.innerHTML` gets all children and their attributes. Whilst it works when an element has no children, if you have an element with children it returns way more than is intended.

Comment: How many "children" do you expect to have in-between your <option>Children?</option> tags?

Answer (score 1):

The [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) selector can be used with [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to retrieve the selected option.

```js
let selectedText = document.querySelector('#selectId option:checked').text;
// or
let selectedText = document.querySelector('#selectId')
      .querySelector('option:checked').text;
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(document.querySelector('#selectId option:checked').text);
});
```

```html
<select id="selectId">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
<button>
Get selected text
</button>
```

For select elements with the [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple) attribute, [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) can be used to obtain all selected options.

```js
let selectedText = [...document.querySelectorAll('#selectId option:checked')]
   .map(o => o.text);
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let selectedText = [...document.querySelectorAll('#selectId option:checked')]
                      .map(o => o.text);
  console.log(selectedText);
});
```

```html
<select id="selectId" multiple>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
<button>
Get selected text
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @artur just without jQuery, with plain javascript:

// Using @Sean-bright's "elt" variable

```
var selection=elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, simple way:

```
const select = document.getElementById('selectID');
const selectedOption = [...select.options].find(option => option.selected).text;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I don't see how this is easy or simple. Why would you use `find()` when you already know the index of the selected item? Also, if there is no selected item (`<select multiple>`), this will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple.  In javascript anything with an ID doesn't need `document.queryselector` or `$('#test')` you can just use test.  Then you simply loop over the selectedOptions which is apart of javascript and you can add it to a new array and use that data how ever you want.

```
let selectedItems = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < test.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
    selectedItems.push(test.selectedOptions[i].text);
}
```

Also

```
// if you want values
selectedItems.push(test.selectedOptions[i].value);
```