# Getting an option text/value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-select

I am trying to build a form that fills in a person's order.

```
<form name="food_select">
    <select name="maincourse" onchange="firstStep(this)">
        <option>- select -</option>
        <option text="breakfast">breakfast</option>
        <option text="lunch">lunch</option>
        <option text="dinner">dinner</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is send in the select object, pull the name and the text/value from the option menu AND the data in the option tag.

```
function firstStep(element) {
    //Grab information from input element object
    /and place them in local variables
    var select_name = element.name;
    var option_value = element.value;
}
```

I can get the name and the option value, but I can't seem to get the text="" or the value="" from the select object. I only need the text/value from the option menu the user selected. I know I can place them in an array, but that doesn't help

```
var option_user_selection = element.options[ whatever they select ].text
```

I also need to use the passed in select reference as that is how it's set up in the rest of my code.

Later on, that text/value is going to be used to pull the XML document that will populate the next select form dynamically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript

Comment: Using jQuery you could do something like `jQuery('#mySelect option[value=myValue]')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the text of the selected <option> in <select> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: rofl, this was 5 years ago...

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use:

```
var option_user_selection = element.options[ element.selectedIndex ].text
```

Comment: Is there a jQuery alternative to this?

Comment: Try this `$("select[name='maincourse'").find('option:selected').text()`

Comment: @Phil the jquery version in my previous comment is in reply to Jacob's request. Can you elaborate n what's awful?

Comment: omgosh, I feel so bad, I thought you were a different guy CORRECTING Chandu, but you ARE Chandu... O_o I deleted my response...

Comment: sweet baby Jesus ! excatly what I needed :)

Comment: You are the massiah.

Comment: @Chandu I liked your commnent, but I have to add a `trim()` at the end to delete unnecessary white spaces.

Answer (score 7):

In jquery you could try this `$("#select_id>option:selected").text()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10574392)

Comment: why not? he want the text of the selected value.... that code returns the selected text on the select...

Comment: It seems like he is not using jq maybe thats why.

Answer (score 4):

```
var option_user_selection = document.getElementById("maincourse").options[document.getElementById("maincourse").selectedIndex ].text
```

Answer (score 3):

```
form.MySelect.options[form.MySelect.selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: This have real educational value. No need for negative marks.