# Way to have a single input to set the value of several different options in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will explain my problem.

I have a select with multiple options, and one (or more) input.
I would like this (these) input are used to give me an additional value to my options.

So, i want with a single input to give an additional value for each option, and that this be kept in memory (without database ^^).

Do you understand ??
Any idea ?
Ty !

Edit :

For example :

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" />
```

I chose option 1 and i set in my input "ok".

I chose option 3 and i set in my input "test".

if i re-chose option 1 i found my value "ok".

Edit 2 : inputs will be a kind of configuration for my options. Each option can have 1 or more input more. An input can have 80 different values​​, if I have 80 options.

Comment: Explain/describe what you want. Give an example. Show us the code you already have.

Comment: Are you rendering this on a server beforehand or is this static HTML?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud If you have ~3500 inputs of static HTML you should find a way to generate that HTML, something as simple as string concatenation in an excel spreadsheet can save you a lot of time.

Comment: In fact, i dont know what is static html in french ;)

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Ah, j'suis désolé. I would call HTML that you would write once and save in a .html file static. Rather HTML that is dynamically generated by server-side framework/language e.g. ASP.NET, PHP and sent as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this version you can change the value of the input and it will be saved.

You can make use of the data- attributes:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/48zdm/)

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="test1">1</option>
  <option value="test2">2</option>
  <option value="test3">3</option>
</select>
<input id="textinput" type="text" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

<script>
$('#select').change(function(){
    $('#textinput').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());
});
$('#textinput').keyup(function(){
    $('#select option:selected').val(this.value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's something like that, but i can have maybe 3500 inputs...^^

Comment: Why are you adding data and adding the overhead of jQuery, when HTML attributes for this already exists?

Comment: I have already a value, i want more and more and more value for one option !

Comment: I think you need to redefine what exactly you want. `i want more and more and more value for one option` I thought there was one value per option

Comment: I want add lots of "values" for an option.. Your example works good i i have one or two input, but not more...

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option text="ok">1</option>
  <option text="hello">2</option>
  <option text="test">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" />

$(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function(){
    $('input').val($('option:selected', this).attr('text'));
  });
});
```

**[Here's a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ohgodwhy/LV6vc/)**

Comment: Is `text` valid? Do you mean `label`?

Comment: @StupidUser Check the fiddle.

Comment: And if i have 40 inputs with 40 differents values for each option ?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Describe the relationship between the inputs and the values. You want to update the value of an input that shares some relationship with the option item?

Comment: The fiddle works. I didn't say it didn't work. There's a difference between functional and valid HTML.

Comment: @StuperUser Text attribute for options is undocumented and supported; you can check it in any browser, including IE 6.

Comment: I know it's supported, but using a documented attribute for the same purpose is more readable/maintainable. If a script is written against this attribute and the page is updated to be rendered by a server-side language that only generates supported attributes scripts can break.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to use the `value` or `label` attribute of an option, see more details at [the Mozilla Developer Network documentation for `<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select#Examples) and [MDN docs for `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option).

See [Getting an option text/value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641962/getting-an-option-text-value-with-javascript) for an example of its use.

Comment: Any reason for a downvote on an answer containing links to references and an example solution?