# How can I show an image based on the selection in a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want my website to post an image as a **result** of a select option value that includes only text. For instance:

```html
<select name="facebook" id="facebook">
  <option value="Facebook"> Facebook </option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
```

The select tag above shows one option with the value "Facebook". When you choose this option and click submit, I want the website to post an image of the Facebook logo (retrieved from a folder or an image URL) based on the option value that was chosen.

Furthermore I insert the values into a table `table_1`, and select the values from the table to echo them on the website. This is the idea of retrieving values and post them as text, but as I said I want to retrieve information but post an **image** instead.

Comment: where do you want to post it to?

Comment: Hi, which language did you use on your backend?

Comment: @Argee, I haven't specified any file I want to post the result in. But The main idea is to retrieve images that I already have stored in a folder, and post the specified image of the select option on perhaps the index page. I don't know if this is what you meant, or?

Comment: Hi @qdequippe, I don't fully understand what you meant by what language I used on my backend. However, the only programming languages I know and use are PHP, HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `img` element next to your button without a source (`src=""`) and then modify it with jQuery using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr). To find the option that is selected from the dropdown (`#select`) you use the [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/#selected1) selector and get the value (`val()`) of it.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
  $('#logo').attr('src', '//via.placeholder.com/150?text=' + $('#select').find(':selected').val()); // replace this with whatever you want
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="logoSelect" id="select">
  <option value="facebook"> Facebook </option>
  <option value="twitter"> Twitter </option>
  <option value="google"> Google </option>
  <option value="instagram"> Instagram </option>
</select>
<button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
<br/><br/>
<img id="logo" src=""></img>
```

You can also achieve this by using pure JavaScript with the [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) and [`.selectIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641968) methods:

```js
const logoImgElem = document.getElementById('logo');
const selectElem = document.getElementById('select');
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
  logoImgElem.src = '//via.placeholder.com/150?text=' + select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
};
```

```html
<select name="logoSelect" id="select">
  <option value="facebook"> Facebook </option>
  <option value="twitter"> Twitter </option>
  <option value="google"> Google </option>
  <option value="instagram"> Instagram </option>
</select>
<button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
<br/><br/>
<img id="logo" src=""></img>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @double-beep. I have a question though, I tried to enter the link you put in the `<script src="">`, and I found a LOT of unknown language. May I ask what this does to the example you posted in your answer? Is this something I need?