# How to Pass innerHTML Argument?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript retrieving the text of the selected option in select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/javascript-retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element)

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1"> Option1 </option>
<option value="2"> Option2 </option>
<option value="3"> Option3 </option>
<option value="4"> Option4 </option>
</select>
```

From the above example, the integer value is being passed to the showUser function by the use of this.value. If instead of passing the value, I wanted to pass the contents of whatever is inside the option tag, like "Option1", how would I do this? I have tried using

```
showUser(this.innerHTML)
```

but that doesn't seem to work, or perhaps I'm approaching it incorrectly. I've looked online at options to use getElementByID but then I think I would need a unique ID for every option.

Comment: I looked at this previously, however I am trying to avoid element IDs for this particular case.

Comment: Then just ignore the `getElementById` step. You already have a reference to the element (`this`). Use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use:

```
showUser(this.selectedIndex >= 0 ? this.options[this.selectedIndex].text : '');
```

See the DOM2 HTML specification's documentation of [`HTMLSelectElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980) and [`HTMLOptionsElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70901257).

Comment: The above code works perfectly if I replace the double quotes "" with single quotes '' at the end. (I think this is because the onchange is already surrounded by quotes). Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this)">
    <option value="">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1"> Option1 </option>
    <option value="2"> Option2 </option>
    <option value="3"> Option3 </option>
    <option value="4"> Option4 </option>
</select>
```

**javascript:**

```
function showUser(obj){
   alert(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].innerHTML);
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vPhq3/1/

Answer (score 1):

In this context, `this` refers to the <select> element, not the selected <option>. I think you want to do `showUser(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)`