# Display selected option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop-down list. After a user selects a language, the selected language is sent to the server. I want to show the selected values on the selected option button.

For example, a user selects a "de", I wish "de'" is displayed on the form, instead of "en".

How can I do this? Thanks

```
<form name="languages" method="post"> 
    <select name="langSelect" onchange=""> 
       <option>en (default)</option> 
       {% for ele in comments.languages.all %} 
           <option>{{ele.lang}}</option> 
       {% endfor %} 
    </select> 
    <div><a  onclick="submitform()">Submit</a></div> 
</form>
```

Comment: where and when do you want to show the values? give your option tags a value attribute **<option value="{{ele.lang}}">{{ele.lang}}</option>**

Comment: you can execute a function similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/javascript-retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element in your submitForm after you've submitted the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, why is your button not a Submit button? If it submits the form you should use `<input type="submit">Submit</input>`

If you use jQuery, then you can say:

```
var selectedVal = $("#langSelect").val();
$("#languages submit").val(selectedVal);
```

I would put this in one statement but did it like this for clarity.

One other thing, you should use the id attribute as well/instead of just Name.

Answer (score 0):

Value of select box will contain selected option value.

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById("langSelect").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use jQuery to achieve that, IE may have some issues (as always): http://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/

In jQuery just type

```
$('[id=langSelect]').val();
```

for getting a value and

```
val('myValue')
```

for setting it. So you may set your name by

```
$('[id=selectedOptionButton]').val($('[id=langSelect]').val());
```