# Inserting select box text into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this has been asked before, however I cannot find a solution to my problem.

I have a select box with three options and three values, these values are used to perform some calculations using JS so I cannot change these to match the option text. This is to work out the amount of V.A.T.

My select looks like this:

```
<select name="tax" id="tax" class="select">
<option value="20">Standard 20%</option>
<option value="0">Zero 0%</option>
<option value="0">Exempt 0%</option>
</select>
```

Which is fine, however I need to insert the text into the database and not the values, as it needs to be viewed in the backend. I have tried a javascript function to add a hidden input to the select box targeting the option that is selected but that was a bit buggy, and didn't seem right. i was thinking of displaying the text next to the value when it is retrieved from the database, however I wouldn't be able to distinguish from the two 0 amounts.

Could someone please offer some further solutions, best approaches to this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you writing this to the database using AJAX?

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/javascript-retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element

Comment: you could use the `data` attribute to hold your calculation values and use the `value` attribute to hold the values you want to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text of the selected option with jQuery as follows:

```
$("#tax option:selected").text();
```

You could easily use this within your AJAX request to send the correct value to the database, just assign it to a variable:

```
var the_text = $("#tax option:selected").text();
```

Failing that, why not just do the lookup in the JS calculations - it'd make your life so much easier:

```
<select name="tax" id="tax" class="select">
    <option value="standard">Standard 20%</option>
    <option value="zero">Zero 0%</option>
    <option value="exempt">Exempt 0%</option>
</select>
```

And your JS could look something like this:

```
var vat_amount = ($('#tax').val() == 'standard') ? 20 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks very much BenM. I implemented the lookup in the JS calculation, and it's now correctly passing the value when the drop down item is selected, (and calculating correctly) Like:   run : function() {
  var amount = $('#net-price-1').val();
  var tax = ($('#tax1').val() == 'standard') ? 20 : 0;
  var tax = ($('#tax1').val() == 'zero') ? 0 : 0;
  var tax = ($('#tax1').val() == 'exempt') ? 0 : 0;

Comment: I forgot to mention changing the variable names for each tax amount, var tax, var tax1 etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the text by JS using the html() function. Or, if you are just using a POST to send the data to the server, try adding both values to the value attribute of the option and split it server side to get the right data.