# Assign a selected <select> option to an input's value

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a `<select>` with 4 `<option>`s and I'm trying to get the selected option into a value of a `<input type="hidden">`.

Here's my code:

```
<form id="selector" name="selector" action="" method="get">
                <label>Number of players: </label><select form="selector" id="selectelement">
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
                <input type="hidden" id="numofplayers" />
                <label> Board size: </label><input type="number" id="board_size" maxlength="2" style="max-width: 20px;" name="board_size" min="3" max="20" />
                <label> Sequence to win: </label><input type="number" id="win_size" maxlength="1" style="max-width: 10px;" name="win_size" min="3" max="9" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
            </form>
```

I tried this:

```
function goform()
{
    this.form.elements["numofplayers"].value =  document.getElementById('selectelement').selectedIndex.innerHTML;
}
```

and in the form tag i do that:

```
<form onsubmit="goform()" id="selector" name="selector" action="" method="get">
```

How do I do that?

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry, I solved it, appearently you can get the value of a selected option by just doing that:

```
var x = document.getElementById("selectelement").value;
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: As you can see in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), `selectedIndex` returns a number, not an HTML element. Hence you cannot use `.innerHTML`.

Comment: And how do I get from an index to the value of the option?

Comment: You can just use `.value` in this case. If the `option` element doesn't have a `value` attribute, it's inner text is used as value.

Answer (score 1):

Search before posting. In any case see: [Retrieving the text of the selected <option> in <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/javascript-retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element)

In your case do:

```
function getSelectedValue(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
}

this.form.elements["numofplayers"].value = getSelectedValue('selectelement');
```

you should be able to go from there.

But by the way, why do you want to do this? You should be able, on the server side to collect the value of the `selectelement` variable since you're populating the value correctly

Comment: OP didn't mention jQuery. *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks your're right! Going to edit it

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onchange` event to assign the value each time the options list has changed:

```
document.getElementById("selectelement").onchange = function() {
    //For values (<option value='1'>1</option>)
    document.getElementById("numofplayers").value = this.value;

    //Actual option text:
    document.getElementById("numofplayers").value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
}
```