# How to get the selected text from form_dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I can't get the text in form_dropdown it always return the option value. Please help.

**view**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<?php 
    $cont ='';
    $dept='';
    foreach($level->result() as $row) {
        $cont = $row->userlevel;
        $dept = $row->department;
    }
    if(strtoupper($cont)=="USER") {
        echo "<strong>".$dept."&emsp;</strong>";
    }
    else {
        echo form_dropdown('department_name', $dept_name,'','id="department_name"');
    } 
?>
<br/><br/>
<div class="btn-group">
    <span id="status2"><?php echo form_dropdown('document_name', $document_name, '', 'id="document_name"'); ?></span>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<label for="file">Select File To Upload:</label>
<input type="file" name="userfile" multiple class="btn btn-file"/>
</br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary"/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var form_data = {
            dept_name: "<?php echo $dept; ?>",
            ajax: 1
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url("document/document_dept_received"); ?>",
            data:form_data,
            type:'POST',
            success: function(msg){
                document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = msg;
            }
        });
    };

    $("#department_name").change(function() {
        var form_data = {
            dept_name: $("#department_name option:selected").text(),
            ajax: 1
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url("document/document_dept_received"); ?>",
            data:form_data,
            type:'POST',
            success: function(msg){
                document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = msg;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**controller**

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data();
$data['thumbnail_name'] = $upload_data['raw_name']. '_thumb' .$upload_data['file_ext'];
$file_array = array(
    'image'         => $data['thumbnail_name'],
    'image_name'    => $upload_data['file_name'],
    //'description'   => "",
    'date_created'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()),
    'date_modified' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', now()),
    'author'        => $this->session->userdata('username'),
    'size'          => $upload_data['file_size'],
    'type'          => $upload_data['image_type'],
    'width'         => $upload_data['image_width'],
    'height'        => $upload_data['image_height'],
    'document_name' => $this->input->post("document_name"),
    'department'    => $this->input->post("department_name"),
    //'notes'         => "",
);
```

when I try this...

```
print_r($this->input->post("document_name"));
print_r($this->input->post("department_name"));
```

it shows 1 and 1...

what I want is the text not the id or value of options. 
Example: I selected the IT Department and Folder 1, it will display/record IT Department and Folder 1 to database.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/javascript-retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element

Comment: I tried to check that. The problem is that I'm using form_dropdown which is connected to database.

Comment: So then you need to create your array as a key/value array, and make the key as a text not an integer.

Comment: But if you want to use integer as an option value, see the link what  i commented. That is exactly what you want, that is get out the selected options text, not the option value.

Comment: no. I want text not integer. I tried to review the link before but not working. see my code I used ajax jquery and I got the text and since I'm using form_open_multipart, the script cannot be applicable to get the text value.

Comment: no. I want text not integer. I tried to review the link before but not working. see my code I used ajax jquery and I got the text and since I'm using form_open_multipart, the script cannot be applicable to get the text value

Answer (score 0):

Exchange array values and keys:

```
$dept_name = array_flip($dept_name);

form_dropdown('department_name', $dept_name,'','id="department_name"');
```

Same for $document_name.

This switches from `<option value="id">name</option>` to `<option value="name">id</option>`.

---

If you need `<option value="name">name</option>`, rebuild the array to get a name 2 name relationship.

```
$dept_names2 = array();

foreach($dept_name as $item_id => $item_name)
{
    $dept_names2[$item_name] = $item_name; // name as key and value
}

form_dropdown('department_name', $dept_names2,'','id="department_name"');
```

An array with structure "name=>name" will work with your ajax requests, too - because you are using `$("#department_name option:selected").text()`. so you are already working with the names, not the ids. no adjustment needed.

Comment: the output is 0 and 0

Comment: show me your $dept_name array: var_dump($dept_name);

Comment: hmm.. the structure of the array is important `array(0=>name)` or `array(name=>name)`. because form_dropdown will insert the array keys as option ids and the array values (names) as option text.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lev0sjjx/2/

**Note:** The jquery code is just for demonstration purposes

**HTML**

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">Test One</option>
    <option value="2">Test Two</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}

$(function() {
    $('#test').change(function() {
        var text = getSelectedText('test');
        alert(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: He has that already: `dept_name: $("#department_name option:selected").text(),`. But this part is not related to the form submit.

Comment: But he want to send it bye ajax, as i understood.

Comment: I'm using form_open_multipart() and form_dropdown()

Comment: Oh :) and i thought he want to send via form submit button .. hehe

Comment: form_open_multipart doesn't matter, since, you want to get text bye javascript, and then send with ajax

Comment: i used ajax only when I selected IT department it will only shows document under that department, what I'm doing is to insert the selected option to database `<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>`

Comment: @jens, yes I want to send via form submit button. because my ajax on for viewing only not for saving the selected options to database

Comment: then you need to build your array like this: `$dept_name = array('IT Department' => 'IT Department');` Through `$_POST` you will get back always the value of the option.