# How to pass html option text as a value for select tag into php $_post using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this following select tag where its option tags are dynamically generated by php:

```
<select  class="form-control "  name="list" id="list" onchange="" >
   <!-- option tags are dynamically generated-->    
</select>
```

these are some sample options that will  be dynamically generated:

```
<option value="1">Item-1</option>
<option value="2">Item-2</option>
<option value="3">Item-3</option>
```

When i use `var_dump($_POST)` i got `array (size=1) 'list' => string '1'` for selecting option `Item-1`.But i want to pass option text like `'list' => string 'Item-1'` to `$_POST`.Also i need the original option value.i try this ajax but didn't work:

`$("#list").val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);`

So what ajax i need to do it in correct way.Thanks

Comment: The idea is that you use the index `value` passed in `$_POST` and either fetch the data again from the database to get the text, or just use the index number and store it in other records on your database as a link to the real text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610336/retrieving-the-text-of-the-selected-option-in-select-element here is your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the option value to the text you want to recieve:

```
<option value="Item-1">Item-1</option>
<option value="Item-2">Item-2</option>
<option value="Item-3">Item-3</option>
```

Or you can get the option text and value like this:

```
var optionText = $("#list option:selected").text();
var optionValue = $("#list").val();
```

and later send it to the server via `jQuery.ajax()` request:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "yourFile.php",
  data: { text: optionText , val: optionValue }
})
  .done(function( result ) {
      // handle the result
  });
```

In the `yourFile.php` you'll have this `$_POST` data:

```
array(
   'text' => 'selected option text',
   'val' => 'selected option value',
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gendos-ua.Nice idea. But i need the value also.However,`var optionText = $("#list option:selected").text();` how can i pass to $_post.Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Gendos-ua.I got it.BTW `data: { text: optionText , val: optionValue }` is this array or object or json ?

Comment: @user5005768 This is a common javascript object. See the link for details - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: This also works `var op = $("#list option:selected"), data = { text: op.prop('text'), val : op.prop('value')  }; $.post('yourFile.php', data).then(...);`

Comment: It is never necessary or beneficial to repeat an option's text as its `value` attribute -- just omit the `value` attribute.